# Bash to get JSON doc from Github

Tags: json, node.js, curl, github

I am trying to do a curl to basically clone a `package.json` in my local directory, by using:

```
curl -U "<email>":"<pass>" -L "https://github.com/flowrepo/blob/master/package.json"
```

I managed to get pass the redirect by using the `-L` flag, but I cannot get a valid JSON doc as the command above is returning the entire Github page. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

Thanks Hans Z. for your answer. This is the final call that works:

```
curl -U "<email>":"<pass>" -L "https://github.com/flowrepo/raw/master/package.json?token<retrieved_token> -o output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the "raw" variant by changing the URL to:

`https://github.com/flowrepo/raw/master/package.json"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regrettably, this is returning the entire html document, not just the JSON I am looking for